# Error: parsererror : SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Trying to submit for using ajax and calculating data with:

```
jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

...but the ajax request fails and gives an error like "unterminated string." I tried using `alert` on the data:

```
alert(jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize());
```

below is the alert output:

```
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=UN5YUZtYEDxVivmtC9dK1AiNjP5Xkdfway6IUkpaleQ%3D&bank_question%5Bname%5D=test1&bank_question%5Buser_instruction%5D=Test2
```

Here is the code for the Ajax request:

```
data = jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
  url: jQuery(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
  data: data,
  type: 'POST',

  success: function(){
    alert("success")
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("error");
  }
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
  "use strict";
  alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' : ' + ex);
})
.always(function() {
   alert("hello"); 
   # add end quote in alert string
 } );
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: can you log/alert this? `jQuery(this).closest('form').attr('action')`. Also this `jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize()`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *actual* error message and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @katana this is the out put  "/admin/audit/bank_questions"

Comment: Yeah, your edit invalidates my answer, now looking for a log of stacktrace.

Comment: @ArvindRajput what is the output of `data` or `jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize()` ?

Comment: alert(jQuery(this).closest('form').serialize()); =>  utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=UN5YUZtYEDxVivmtC9dK1AiNjP5Xkdfway6IUkpaleQ%3D&bank_question%5Bname%5D=test1&bank_question%5Buser_instruction%5D=Test2

Comment: ok show `console.log(jQuery(this).closest('form').serializeArray())` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit explained the reason for the "unterminated string literal" error and helped you fix it. You're now describing a different problem. You should accept ArupRakshit's answer and post a new question with a complete description of the new problem you're having. This question has been answered.

Comment: @arup this is the out put - [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: What type of response does the server send back? If it's JSON, the problem may be that the JSON is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: The most common cause of this error is trying to split a string across multiple lines.

Comment: @Barmar type of response is  - text/javascript; charset=utf-8

Comment: It sounds like the response isn't valid Javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your efforts that's was a mistake by me in rjs file fixed it .by mistake i have written jQuery("#id'). mistake in single and double Quatto